# Can I pop from RabbitMQ queue based on routing key associated to that message?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

My scenario is such that I want to have one queue for the producer where the published messages will be stored. The messages will be associated with some routing key such that abcd.1234(some id).
Now from the consumer part I want that every consumer will connect to this queue and pop the messages based on the routing key pattern. Such as say consumer for abcd.123 will pop the messages with routing key abcd.123 and so on.
I tried to use topic exchange but I don't think its directly fitting into this use case as topic exchange generates one queue for each subscriber(consumer)

So, in there any way to consume (pop) message from queue based on the routing key of that queue.
Similar to queue.pop(:routing_key:xyz)

kindly help on this how to proceed?

Comment: based on the queue.Consume method documentation, all it takes is a queue name. So, no. One option is to query the queues api and get all the active queues (http://localhost:15672/api/queues)